# use jquery to change css background image

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change a CSS background image using jQuery, and the code I am using just reloads the current image.
When you click the li#menu-item-23, I want the div with the class of #changeMe to switch background images

```
$('li#menu-item-23').click(function(){
  $('#changeMe').css('background-image','url(i/logo4.png)');

});
```

Comment: add quotes inside your url `... 'url("i/logo4.png")' ...`

Comment: verify your image path. It should be relative to your current URL.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url("i/logo4.png")');
```

You need to add double quotes inside `url()`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/92m4309b/7/)**

Also make sure you image path is correct...

**Here is a brief description of the file paths:**

`./` means the current directory

`../` means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory

`/` is the root directory

`myfile.text` is in the current directory, as is `./myfile.text`

`../myfile.text` is one level above you and `/myfile.text` lives in your root directory.

Comment: Here is a fiddle for the above: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/92m4309b/7/ (You beat me to writing the answer)

Comment: @imbondbaby still no luck unfortunately.  I'm working in Wordpress, and I wonder if that is somehow affecting things.  My other jQuery works fine, this is the only piece that's failing

Comment: Wrap it around `document.ready` function and see if that makes a difference... Are you sure the image path is correct?

Comment: @imbondbaby I think you're right, there's something weird going on with the image path.. haven't needed to access an image url through jQuery in WP before